# Data transfer From access to MSSQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I got a database in my central MSSQL server and I got an access version with new data on my desktop. Will I be able to transfer the new data into the central MSSQL server database from the access database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Data Import from SSMS.

1. Right click on DB
2. select Tasks
3. Import data..
4. Select your Access DB as source
5. Set the mappings etc from your source to destination

You can save this as an [SSIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155829/SQL-Server-Integration-Services-SSIS-Part-1-Basics) package to either re-run at a later date or to develop in [BIDS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for a more advanced import toolset.

Comment: Simple and good tool but there is no chance to do any data conversion and other manipulation, it's quite straightforward.

Comment: will it notify you if there is a duplicate data trying to be imported?

Comment: If your table should not have duplicates, add a unique key (sorry, had to run out there at point 4 for fire drill)

Comment: tried it seems ok till I get to the point where I'm adding the database and when I go next I get this error (Cannot Start your application.The Workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user). I am sure the database is closed and no 1 is using it because it's in my local machine only

Comment: is it Password protected or have spaces in the path?

Comment: it's an .mdb got no space and it is password protected but when I don't put the password it gives me an error saying password not entered r something like that and when I put the password I get the error I mentioned above.

Comment: for the sake of loading it, can you unprotect? I mean spaces in the full path, like C:\my path\mydb.mdb ?

Comment: In my experience, getting SQL Server/SSIS to talk to Access is a pain; it's much easier to get Access to talk to SQL Server.

Comment: I guess you could also dump the access data to CSV and load this way, at least you will have a SSIS package set up for future?

Answer (score 2):

You can link your SQL Server tables into your Access database - use the External Data menu. Then you can write standard Access append queries to move data between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one powerful tool for Data Export/Import and that is **SQL Server integration Services** or **SSIS**. There you can, not just move data, but do some simple or complex data manipulation, like conversion, mapping, lookup and other...

SSIS are SQL service which can be installed from installation media, and it will be installed only once, because, they are independent of instance, actually belong to *shared components*.

Beside noted, they are capable of scheduling package execution, so you can do it more times, without any additional work. They are usually used in ETL systems.

They offer rich GUI with many graphical components, so your administration and creation are very easy.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access has an upsizing wizard to move data from an Access project to an existing SQL Server database, or create a new one.

I've had to use it before when using Access as a staging platform when using from some anarchic databases up to SQL Server.

There's a guide on how to use it here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/use-the-upsizing-wizard-HP005273009.aspx